# How can I avoid subscript out of bounds in building my website in R?

Tags: r, project, subscript

So I have a project in R that's a statistical math notebook. I have been adding links to the _site.yml throughout the semester. This weekend I updated R, and for some reason every time I knit .rmds within the notebook I get the following error.

> Error in config$output[["html_document"]] : subscript out of bounds
>   Calls:  ->  -> patch_html_document_options
>   Execution halted
>
> Exited with status 1.

I get the same error when I try building the whole website. I also tried to knit .rmds outside the notebook, and that was successful. I have searched everywhere for a similar issue but I couldn't really find anything that related, (or maybe my google searching isn't that good). In any case, it would be nice to have my .rmds knit successfully in this notebook. I have also uninstalled Rstudio and reinstalled it and that didn't work either. 
Here is my _site.yml (Although I don't know it will help).

```
name: "math-325-notebook"
navbar:
  title: "Math 325 Notebook"
  left:
    - text: "Table of Contents"
      href: index.html
    - text: "Describing Data"
      menu:
        - text: "Graphical Summaries"
          href: GraphicalSummaries.html
        - text: "Numerical Summaries"
          href: NumericalSummaries.html
    - text: "Making Inference"
      menu: 
        - text: "Making Inference"
          href: MakingInference.html
        - text: "t Tests"
          href: tTests.html
        - text: "Wilcoxon Tests"
          href: WilcoxonTests.html
        - text: "ANOVA"
          href: ANOVA.html
        - text: "Kruskal-Wallis"
          href: Kruskal.html
        - text: "Linear Regression"
          href: LinearRegression.html
        - text: "Logistic Regression"
          href: LogisticRegression.html
    - text: "R Help"
      menu:
        - text: "R Commands"
          href: RCommands.html
        - text: "R Markdown Hints"
          href: RMarkdownHints.html
    - text: "Analyses"
      menu:
        - text: "Analysis Rubric"
          href: ./Analyses/AnalysisRubric.html
        - text: "Good Example Analysis"
          href: ./Analyses/StudentHousing.html
        - text: "Poor Example Analysis"
          href: ./Analyses/StudentHousingPOOR.html
        - text: "My First Analysis"
          href: ./Analyses/StudentHousingII.html

output_dir: '.'
```

Most of the posts I read about subscript out of bounds related to arrays that they were trying to get numbers out of the domain, which I don't think is related in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so people know, I had this answered, it ended up being the rmarkdown library, there was some sort of bug in the latest version, I installed the version before it appears to be working fine in this aspect, I have another bug now elsewhere, but I think I can fix that.